# SQL complicated join with if conditions

Tags: sql-server, join

I am writing a long query to get some data together. Here is a mock data:

Table1:

```
a|b|c|d|e   
1|1|2|2|134
```

Table2:
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2 is a composite key

```
a2|b2|c2|d2|e2  |f2    |ax2|bx2|cx2|dx2|ex2  
1 |1 |2 |2 |134 |Orange|1  |1  |2  |2  |155  
1 |1 |2 |2 |155 |Apple |Null|Null|Null|Null|Null
```

My query is something like this:

```
Select * from Table1  
inner join  
Table2 on Table1.a=Table2.a2 and Table1.b=Table2.b2 and Table1.c=Table2.c2 and Table1.d=Table2.d2 and Table1.e=Table2.e2
```

This gives me

> Orange

The answer i need is

> Apple

Table 2 is pretty messed up and so what I am trying to do is to get a,b,c,d,e from Table1 and then plug it into Table2, get the ex2 value, run Table2 again to get Apple by replacing e2 with ex2 while leaving a2,b2,c2,d2 the same.

Like I mentioned it is a bit complicated so please ask for more details if you need. I have tried to give as much as possible.

I tried this too (still no joy):

```
Select y.a2,y.b2,y.c2,y.d2,(Select case when e2 is not null and ex2 is not null then ex2 else e2 end) from Table1 x inner join Table2 y on x.a=y.a2 and x.b=y.b2 and x.c=y.c2 and x.d=y.d2 and Table1.e=Table2.e2
```

Comment: You need to give real table structure and actual query or it's going to be difficult to help.

Comment: It should get you orange E2 is 134 in both table1 and table2.  Why should it give you 155?  oh it's a hierarchy.  is the hierachy always just 1 level? if so add a join again to table2 if it could be n levels then you need a recursive cte or to use for xml path to traverse the hierarchy.

Comment: @xQbert in some cases the answer is Apple/Orange. Table 1 would give you Orange if you use e2 with it from Table 2. If you want Apple as well then you need to get the value of ex2 and plug it in e2 to get Apple. So yes it is sort of a hierarchy.

Comment: Based on your sample data, the answer should be Orange.

Comment: @xQbert yes it is always just 1 level as ax2,bx2,..ex2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another join to the query as left joins to traverse the extra level and use coalesce to show the lowest level if it exists, or the next lowest if it doesn't.

```
SELECT Coalesce(C.F2, B.F2) as F2
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B
  on A.a= b.a2
 and A.B = B.B2 
 and A.C = B.C2
 and A.D = B.D2
 and A.E = B.E2
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C
  on B.Ax2 = C.A2
 and B.Bx2 = C.B2
 and B.Cx2 = C.c2
 and B.Dx2 = C.D2
 and B.Ex2 = C.E2
```

Comment: this did the job!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with temporary tables.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table1;
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    a int not null,
    b int not null,
    c int not null,
    d int not null,
    e int not null,
);
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, 1, 2, 2, 134);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table2;
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
    a2 int not null,
    b2 int not null,
    c2 int not null,
    d2 int not null,
    e2 int not null,
    f2 nvarchar(10) not null,
    ax2 int null,
    bx2 int null,
    cx2 int null,
    dx2 int null,
    ex2 int null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY (a2, b2, c2, d2, e2),
);
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 2, 134, 'Orange', 1, 1, 2, 2, 155),
    (1, 1, 2, 2, 155, 'Apple', null, null, null, null, null);

SELECT Branch.a2
    , Branch.b2
    , Branch.c2
    , Branch.d2
    , Leaf.e2
    , Leaf.f2
FROM #Table1 AS Root
INNER JOIN #Table2 AS Branch
    ON Root.a = Branch.a2
    AND Root.b = Branch.b2
    AND Root.c = Branch.c2
    AND Root.d = Branch.d2
    AND Root.e = Branch.e2
INNER JOIN #Table2 AS Leaf
    ON Branch.ex2 = Leaf.e2;
```

Result is

```
+---------------------+
|a2|b2|c2|d2|e2 |f2   |
+---------------------+
| 1| 1| 2| 2|155|Apple|
+---------------------+
```

Comment: your query worked as well but xQbert got it first. Much appreciated!

Comment: Left join instead of inner incase there's not a leaf?  as would be the case on 155?

Comment: Sure, if that is one's intent. It is a bit difficult to tell from the question.